# Alerta sonoro em HTML

Tags: php, html

Estou populando as informações de uma tabela com os dados do BD. Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de verificar linha a linha que esta chegando e emitir um sinal sonoro apenas para as linhas novas dentro das condições que eu criei.

Observem que já criei uma condição de alerta, porém, aparece para todos, até ai tudo certo, mas se eu colocar o som, ele vai tocar toda hora, pois as informações ainda estarão ali. Quero fazer um `if` para cada linha nova e desconsiderar aquelas que já foram verificadas.

Utilizei a seguinte linha para emitir o som:

```
<embed src="alert.mp3" width="1" height="1" type=""></embed>


<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td><b>valor1</b></td>
  <td><b>valor2</b></td>
  <td><b>valor3</b></td>
  <td><b>valor4</b></td>
  <td><b>valor5</b></td>
</tr>
<?php 
foreach ($read as $key => $value) {
  $lista = $value['obs'];
  ?>
  <tr <?php if($lista == "teste"){echo 'class="table-danger"';} ?>>
    <td><?php echo $value['valor1']; ?></td>
    <td><img width="150" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo $value['valor2']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($value['valor2'])); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['valor4']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value['valor5']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: "desconsiderar aquelas que já foram verificadas", como você sabe quais já foram verificadas?

Comment: A final, qual o problema: tocar o som ou identificar as novas linhas para então tocar o som?

Comment: Porque utilizar som? A aplicação vai ser adaptada para deficientes visuais?

Comment: Percebam que já coloquei um alert: if($lista == "teste"){echo 'class="table-danger"';}, as condições para tocar o som(Alerta), também são as mesmas. Porém se eu trocar a linha, ele ficará tocando infinitamente. Quero q ele desconsidere as que já passaram e verifica apenas aquela que vai ser atualizada.

Comment: O som é um Alerta apenas. Alertar e parar. Eu atualizo com um refresh a pagina a cada 8 seg